# How can I extend MvcForm so that It will not generate a form tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to add a condition to a html beginform.
If the condition is false, I dont want the form tag to be generated.

Similar to this code:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString If(this MvcHtmlString value, bool evaluation)
        {
            return evaluation ? value : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something similar for a one off feature.  This is proof of concept code but it looked something like:

```
public class NoForm : IDisposable
{
  // Whatever this suppose to look like
  // but actually does nothing
  public void Dispose() { } 
}
```

In the view:

```
@{
  IDisposable form;
  if (Model canShowForm)
  {
    form = Html.BeginForm(...);
  }
  else
  {
    form = new NoForm()
  }
}

@using (form)
{
  @* we might be in a form *@
}
```

Obviously this could be refactored into an HtmlHelper extension method, I just haven't done it.